# CSS positioning of a div

Tags: html, css

I use [this spinning](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/#!) library which generates a div positioned relative and I have the following HTML code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <a href="a-link">LINK</a> IMPORTANT-TEXT
   </td>
   <td>
   </td>
     Something not important
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now I have a problem positioning the generated relative div right after `IMPORTANT-TEXT`.
So far I have tried to make a `<div class="spinning-container" style="position:absolute; margin:-10px 0 0px 30px"/>` and to render the generated div into the spinning-container, but I do not know the length of the `IMPORTANT-TEXT`

PS: The content should not overlap.

**EDIT:**
Example of what I have tried so far: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kALAB/3/).

Comment: Could you provide some more code or a fiddle?

Comment: @AndreiI That's the blankest jsfiddle I ever did see :P

Comment: @Agony sorry. Solved :)

Comment: @AndreiI Not to be a "nudge", but it's still blank. You have to click "Save" or "Update" in the top bar on jsfiddle.net to save your progress.

Comment: @Agony The URL changed when I saved it, and that's why it was a new URL. Updated the URL. Thanks for patience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what possible solutions you would want, but you could always define the Important Text size to what you would like, then position the spinning div based on that.

Ex.
CSS

```
#importext{
max-width:200px;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <a href="a-link">LINK</a> <div id="importext">IMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXTIMPORTANT-TEXT</div>
   </td>
   <td>
   </td>
     Something not important
   </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
spinDiv = jQuery('<div class="spinning-div" style="position:absolute; margin:-25px 0 0px 220px"/>');
```

Here's a JSFiddle example. I also tweeked the margins of the spinner. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/kALAB/6/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a larger margin to the div to push it over next to the next.

http://jsfiddle.net/kALAB/5/

```
spinDiv = jQuery('<div class="spinning-div" style="position:absolute; margin:-10px 0 0px 200px"/>');
```

Comment: In this case the spinner would appear not "right after" `IMPORTANT-TEXT` and there will be some space in between the text and the spinner, depending on how wide the table is.

Comment: @AndreiI I saw a messed up fiddle before you updated it. Look at my solution now

Comment: IMPORTANT-TEXT is dynamic (from database) and thus can be of 250px or 300px.

Comment: Well the problem is the spinner. If you inspect the element in the developer tools you can see that it really is a lot of tiny divs that are absolute positioned. So they dont want to move anywhere thus why you have to put them all in a larger absolute positioned div. So you can have it be relative to what your database returns. @AndreiI

Comment: @AndreiI Another thing you could try is just downloading a loading gif and put that in an image tag and it will be a lot easier to position

Comment: The problem with the gif is that this JS library is already used in the application and I want to use it again in order to remain consistent.